# Back End Not working - After tried install 3rd party Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, error, extensions

Tried to install payment charge extension, i get error on installation process, and back end is not working.

Error like.

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Locale_Data' not found in
>   /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php on
>   line 171

How can i solve this error?

Comment: Sounds like something messed up either the library or corresponding permissions. Make sure file `lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php` still exists and its permissions are set correctly, i.e. your webserver can read it.

Comment: check if your compile is enable then disable your compile

Comment: Bro, how can i disable my compile, instead backend admin not working.

Comment: from terminal or cmd

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something messed up either the library or corresponding permissions. Make sure file `lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php` still exists and its permissions are set correctly, i.e. your webserver can read it.

Comment: there is no file what you mentioned ??

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QL96a0V.png

Comment: This file should definitely be there. You have to deploy it – and possible other folders missing up the path – from source control or a working local copy.

Comment: any other possible options ??